# Gtk Widget into a Winform

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

Is it possible to embed a Gtk widget into an application using System.Windows.Forms? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both toolkits use their own separate "UI Mainloop" to process events (such as mouse moves, button presses, etc.). As such, mixing the two is effectively impossible. Although there was talk on the Gtk# mailinglist several years ago about attempting to use a custom mainloop that pumped the event handling of each toolkit to enable such an approach, I don't think anything stable or useful came from it.