# Winforms and GTK# in one application

Tags: c#, winforms, gtk#

I have a question: Is it possible to build an application, which is using Windows Forms and GTK# windows at the same time? I tried to make something like that, but it seems, that Gtk.Application.Run() is blocking winforms application.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689250/gtk-widget-into-a-winform) is certainly related, though not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

O.R. Mapper's link is the valid explanation.